# Programmatically Create Survival Curves

Tags: statistics, web-statistics

i am using vb.net / asp.net

my team created a web application (research database for cancer center)

i am wondering if anyone has an idea about drawing survival curves programmatically

i searched every where and couldnt find any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to study the equation of kaplan meier thoroughly and then try to do it using vb.net or c# datatable, then chart it using mschart control.

Please check this article

[The use of MS Chart Control and VB.NET for Statistical Purposes: Plotting Kaplan-Meier Estimate.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491394/The-use-of-MS-Chart-Control-and-VB-NET-for-Statist)